# output of spacy convert command not compatible with spacy train command

Tags: spacy

I wanted to convert conllu format for Hindi to json using spacy convert and it is generating jsonl format. When I pass on the same .jsonl file to spacy train I am getting an error. If I pass a json file to the train command, it is working. Shouldn't the output of spacy convert be compatible with spacy train?

The error message is as follows:

[image: Keyerror 1 for spacy train]

I am using :
Spacy version - 2.1.3
Python 3.6.8
ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem when outputting convertions as *default jsonl format*. Fixed by converting with file-type : json attribute e.g.

```
python -m spacy convert lang_train.conllu output-folder --file-type json
```